# ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure after :server connect for neo4j

Tags: docker, websocket, neo4j

I want to launch Neo4j on my machine with dokcer. I downloaded it and did it:

```
docker run -p 7474:7474 neo4j
```

But on http://localhost:7474/browser/ I have:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> *ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3*

I tried with neo4j/neo4j credentials and it gave me the same error.

I thought to edit `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf` and uncommenting:

```
# To have Bolt accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

as they say [in the following method](https://community.neo4j.com/t/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure-due-to-security-constraints-in-your-web-browser-the-reason-for-the-failure-is-not-available-to-this-neo4j-driver/259) but I was not able to find the file

```
bash-5.1$  cd /var/lib/
abrt/                  games/                 PackageKit/
AccountsService/       gdm/                   plymouth/
alsa/                  geoclue/               polkit-1/
alternatives/          gssproxy/              portables/
authselect/            hp/                    power-profiles-daemon/
bluetooth/             httpd/                 private/
chrony/                hyperv/                rpm/
cni/                   initramfs/             rpm-state/
color/                 iscsi/                 samba/
colord/                kdump/                 selinux/
containerd/            libvirt/               sss/
containers/            lockdown/              systemd/
dbus/                  logrotate/             texmf/
dhclient/              machines/              tpm/
dnf/                   misc/                  tpm2-tss/
dnsmasq/               mlocate/               udisks2/
docker/                net-snmp/              unbound/
fedora-third-party/    NetworkManager/        upower/
flatpak/               nfs/                   xkb/
fprint/                openvpn/               
fwupd/                 os-prober/
```

Comment: You need to use the default user/pass, which is neo4j/neo4j

Comment: I just tried @TomažBratanič and it gives me the same error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to expose the bolt port from the docker container. The default bolt port is 7687.

```
docker run -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j
```